# iOS Chrome losing its cookies?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, web-browsing, cookies

Using Google Chrome on my iPad, it seems like every now and then it randomly "forgets" all of my cookies. Authentication cookies in particular; I get re-prompted for two factor authentication and notified "you may be clearing cookies if you see this message often".
I am not clearing my cookies manually, nor does there seem to be any rhyme or reason to the cookies disappearing. It is not a particular amount of time -- sometimes it is multiple times a week, and I never use Incognito Mode.

This has happened ever since I remember installing Chrome on my ipad a year or so ago.
It does not happen with desktop or android versions of Chrome. Just the iOS version.

Is this a known issue? Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: iOS Chrome is nothing a Safari wrapped (UIWebView) with a Google UI. Knowing that, do you have the same issues with Safari ?

Comment: Chrome is the only browser I've ever used on iOS, except when forced by OS hooks to use Safari.  I'll have to start using Safari for awhile to see if I can simulate that. Does this mean that Safari and Chrome share cookies on iOS? Or that there might be a Safari setting that I can change to fix it? (I won't be able to check on my ipad again until tonight, but I'll report back asap)

Comment: I haven't yet had a chance to reproduce the behavior outside of Chrome, but I promise I will post an update here one way or the other within a few days.

Comment: Still can't reproduce the behavior outside of Chrome, but I have at least proven that Safari and Chrome do *not* share cookies in the first place. So it still seems Chrome-specific.